# How to apply adjustment factor to stock prices in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables -  Table A(Stock prices with date and symbols) and Table B(Adjustment factor and the effective date *adjustment factor is applicable for all dates before the effective date)

**Table A -**

| date | symbol | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-23 | IRCON | 45 |
| 2021-07-23 | TIDEWATER | 14891 |
| 2021-07-22 | TIDEWATER | 15309 |
| 2021-07-22 | IRCON | 45 |
| 2020-04-03 | IRCON | 91 |
| 2020-04-03 | TIDEWATER | 3182 |
| 2020-04-01 | IRCON | 393 |
| 2020-04-01 | TIDEWATER | 3171 |
| 2020-03-31 | IRCON | 381 |
| 2020-03-31 | TIDEWATER | 3207 |

**Table B -**

| symbol | effective_date | adjustment_factor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TIDEWATER | 2021-07-26 | 3 |
| IRCON | 2021-07-26 | 2 |
| IRCON | 2020-04-03 | 5 |

Requirement is -
The adjustment_factor of symbol needs to be applied(as a divisor) to Prices of symbol for all the dates less than effective_date of that adjustment_factor

**E.g-** For IRCON and adjustment_factor of 2 dated 2021-07-26, all prices of IRCON in Table A earlier than 2021-07-26 need to be divided by 2.
Similarly, for IRCON, adjustment_factor of 5 dated 2021-04-03,all prices of IRCON in Table A earlier than 2021-04-03 need to be divided by 5
(so, effectively all prices of IRCON before 2021-04-03 need to be divided by 2x5=10)

**Desired output -**

| date | symbol | price | adjustment_factor | adjusted_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-23 | IRCON | 45 | 2 | 22.38 |
| 2021-07-23 | TIDEWATER | 14891 | 3 | 4963.75 |
| 2021-07-22 | TIDEWATER | 15309 | 3 | 5103.00 |
| 2021-07-22 | IRCON | 45 | 2 | 22.58 |
| 2020-04-03 | IRCON | 91 | 2 | 45.43 |
| 2020-04-03 | TIDEWATER | 3182 | 3 | 1060.50 |
| 2020-04-01 | IRCON | 393 | 10=2x5 | 39.30 |
| 2020-04-01 | TIDEWATER | 3171 | 3 | 1057.13 |
| 2020-03-31 | IRCON | 381 | 10=2x5 | 38.10 |
| 2020-03-31 | TIDEWATER | 3207 | 3 | 1069.13 |

I have been trying using INNER JOIN, however, I am stuck for prices that need to be divided multiple times. There are some prices that need to be adjusted/divided with 5-6 factors combined/multiplied together. Is it possible to write some query for this in Postgres, maybe using Windows functions? Is there any scalable query to do this?

Comment: 45 / 2 is 22.500 - why do you expect 22.38 in the first row of your output? I also don't understand the logic about "divided b 2*5" - what if you had 10 rows for IRCON before `2021-04-03`? Should all factors be multiplied before the division? You also seem to be mixing up 2020-04-03 and 2021-04-03 in the description of the rules

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there must be a better solution, But till the time you are not finding a better solution, You may try below solution -

```
SELECT A.date, A.symbol, A.price,
       (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT adjustment_factor
                           FROM B B2
                          WHERE B1.symbol = B2.symbol
                            AND B1.effective_date < B2.effective_date), 1)*B1.adjustment_factor adjustment_factor
          FROM B B1
         WHERE A.symbol = B1.symbol
           AND A.date < B1.effective_date
         ORDER BY B1.effective_date
         LIMIT 1),
        ROUND(A.price :: DECIMAL / (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT adjustment_factor
                                                       FROM B B2
                                                      WHERE B1.symbol = B2.symbol
                                                        AND B1.effective_date < B2.effective_date), 1)*B1.adjustment_factor
                                      FROM B B1
                                     WHERE A.symbol = B1.symbol
                                       AND A.date <= B1.effective_date
                                     ORDER BY B1.effective_date
                                     LIMIT 1), 2) adjusted_price
  FROM A;
```

[Fiddle Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a4b85/33)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join.  The real trick is that Postgres (and SQL in general) does not offer a `product()` aggregation function.  However, you can implement one using logs and exponentiation:

```
select a.*,
       b.net_adjustment_factor,
       a.price / coalesce(b.net_adjustment_factor, 1)
from a left join lateral
     (select exp(sum(ln(adjustment_factor)) over (partition by symbol order by effective_date)) as net_adjustment_factor
      from b
      where b.symbol = a.symbol and
            b.effective_date >= a.date
     ) b
     on 1=1;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tMfBoov5CpNCuit6hj2eHC/0) is a db-fiddle.